# Selecting MYSQL database in SQL-Developer

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a database in MYSQL naming "X" (for example). When i create a new connection and select the database in SQL-Developer, i get only "information_schema" and "test", the default table provided my MYSQL.

How should i get the manually created database name in SQL-Developer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, here i got my answer :

create a user and provide access privilege for that manually creates database. After that in SQL-Developer create the same username as created in the database.